# Using React Native with Buildfire

Tags: reactjs, native, buildfire

Having trouble getting a clear answer if we can build plugins in React Native to use with Buildfire, or can one only use React?

On Github, there is a React template, but none for React Native.

We tried building one and have run into some issues. Trying to find out if it's even possible.

Has anyone done this or know the answer?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is No. You can use ReactJS but not React Native. The whole value proposition of BuildFireJS is to remove the complexity of dealing with lower level frameworks like Cordova or React Native. BuildFire’s plugin system to build modular apps forces you to build features focusing on function without worrying about environment.